# How to make a Password Checker?

Tags: python, passwords

I trying to make a Password Checker where the user is asked to enter a password between 8 and 24 characters (if out of this range, an error message is displayed). Also, to have points added or subtracted depending on the length of password entered by the user.

> If there is at least one 'capital', 'lower case', 'symbol' or 'number': 
>   add 5 points.
>
> If there is a capital and a number and a lower: add 15 points.
>
> If entered password is in the form of 'QWERTY': subtract 15 points.

Here is my code so far:

```
passcheck = input("Enter a password to check: ") 

passlength = len(passcheck)

symbols = {'!','$','%','^','&','*','(',')','-','_','=','+'}
qwerty = ["qwertyuiop", "asdfghjkl", "zxcvbnm"]

upper = sum(1 for character in passcheck if character.isupper())
lower = sum(1 for character in passcheck if character.islower())
num = sum(1 for character in passcheck if character.isnumeric())
sym = passcheck.count('!$%^&*()_-+=')

if passlength <8 or passlength >24:
    print("ERROR. Password must be between 8-24 characters long")
else:
    if upper in passcheck > 0:
        score += 5
    if lower in passcheck > 0:
        score += 5
    if num in passcheck > 0:
        score += 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
import sys

passcheck = input("Enter a password to check: ")

checking=set(passcheck)

passlength = len(passcheck)

points=0

symbols = {'!','$','%','^','&','*','(',')','-','_','=','+'}
qwerty = ["qwertyuiop", "asdfghjkl", "zxcvbnm"]




if passlength <8 or passlength >24:
    print("ERROR. Password must be between 8-24 characters long")


else:

    for i in qwerty:

        if i in passcheck:  #If entered password is in the form of 'QWERTY': subtract 15 points.
            points-=15
            print("your password contain form of 'QWERTY' , Don't use weak password.")
            print(points)
            sys.exit()

if any(i.islower() for i in checking) or any(i.isupper() for i in checking) or any(i for i in checking if i in symbols) or any(i.isdigit() for i in checking):
    points+=5  #If there is at least one 'capital', 'lower case', 'symbol' or 'number': add 5 points.


if any(i.islower() for i in checking) and any(i.isupper() for i in checking) and any(i.isdigit() for i in checking):
    points+=15 #If there is a capital and a number and a lower: add 15 points.



print(points)
```